# Blur edges of a star shape in GIMP

Tags: gimp, blur

I created a circle with blurred edges by making an ellipse selection and filling it with pencil, brush Pixel (3x3). This is how it looks.

[image: Circle]

I would like to create a star with a similar style but I failed at creating blurred edges.

[image: Star]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Free Select tool (aka Lasso tool) in GIMP to make a star shape. In the tool options make sure anti-aliasing is checked (see tool options under the tool box in the example). This will ensure it has an anti-aliased edge like the circle.

Then draw the star by clicking all the corner points, adjust the corners by clicking and dragging the handles until it looks good, then fill it with white.

Example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Completely different solution:

1. Create a star brush

   - `Windows ➤ Dockable dialog ➤ Brush`
   - Click the `+` icon at the bottom
   - Use the settings:

     - Shape: diamond (`⯁`)
     - Radius: size you want
     - Spikes: 5
     - Hardness: 1.00 (full right)
     - Aspect ratio: sets how pointy the star is
     - Angle: to taste
     - Spacing: irrelevant
   - Keep the brush editor up
2. Start the paint brush tool and try the brush. If you don't like it, you can change the brush in the editor.
3. You can tweak the `Hardness` of the brush to blur it. This gives a blur which is a bit different from a Gaussian blur applied to a hard star.

[image]